# Filtrar para que solo sean 2 select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un dropdownlist donde se conecta a una tabla de sql, y en esa tabla tengo solo 2 valores de "Agente" y " Supervisor".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el view así me aparece, pero quiero que no se repita y solo sea Agente y Supervisor.

Aquí tengo el codigo del controlador:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ServicioNivelId = new SelectList(db.ServicioNiveles, "ServicioNivelId", "Descripcion");


            ViewBag.Rol = new SelectList(db.Agentes, "Rol", "Rol");
            
            return View();
        }
```

Y en el view:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rol, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Rol, (SelectList)ViewBag.Rol, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rol, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es SelectList? Podrías añadir el constructor para dar mas contexto a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambie en el controlador la variable con otra estructura.

```
 var tabla = db.Agentes.Select(x => x.Rol).Distinct().ToList();
            var lista = new SelectList(tabla);
            ViewBag.Rol = lista;
```

Y en el view, cambie  el dropdownlistfor por uno sencillo.